# angular fire querying-collections docs sample code not working

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I was reading on the angular fire docs specifically this one https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

somewhere down below where the sample code is

```
this.items$ = combineLatest(
  this.sizeFilter$,
  this.colorFilter$
).pipe(
  switchMap(([size, color]) => 
    afs.collection('items', ref => {
      let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      if (size) { query = query.where('size', '==', size) };
      if (color) { query = query.where('color', '==', color) };
      return query;
    }).valueChanges()
  )
);
```

I get this error from "this.items$"

> Type 'Observable<unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item[]>'.
> Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Item[]'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Item': text, color,size(2322)

What did I miss?

I am using Visual Studio Code and these are the versions of Angular and angular fire

Angular v10.0.4
@angular/fire@^6.0.2

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a few days now. I hope someone can give an advice.

Comment: How and where did u init sizeFilter$ and colorFilter$? Same as in the example?

Comment: u are missing the typeannotation in the generic <> --> afs.collection<Item>. Thats Why it returns an Uknown[] error.

Comment: just like the example yes

Comment: @sagat do you mean it should have been like this afs.collection<interface class name>('collection name')

Comment: yes, just like in my answer

Comment: huh... I was over thinking it and trusting the docs so much. works. thanks @sagat

Comment: nice would u pls accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Generic type in the `afs.colelction`, should be --> `afs.collection<Item>`. Thats Why it returns an `Unknown[]` error.

```
this.items$ = combineLatest(
  this.sizeFilter$,
  this.colorFilter$
).pipe(
  switchMap(([size, color]) => 
    afs.collection<Item>('items', ref => { // generic type required here
      let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      if (size) { query = query.where('size', '==', size) };
      if (color) { query = query.where('color', '==', color) };
      return query;
    }).valueChanges()
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have been overthinking and over trusting the docs so much. Thanks @sagat for another look on this one. The Angular Fire docs needs to be updated.

The docs should have wrote the code like this

```
afs.collection<Item>('items')
```

It does not bother Visual Studio Code anymore.